# Verifying if a text exists on a webpage in QTP

Tags: qtp

I have a web page which consists of different words that are present in sets of 2, how do I confirm in QTP that these words are present on the webpage

In the attached image i have series of tests in order, (The order stays same) however I have to do a definite check if that text is present on the webpage. [image]

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Do you need to verify only the text ? what is the type is it a web element ?

Comment: No I need to check that everytime i scan through the page, the text is present it is not a hyper link but text on the page

Answer (score 3):

you can "Instr"  to find out e.g - 
InStr([start, ]string1, string2[, compare]), so you can use something like -

```
mytext = browser().Page().WebElement().GetROProperty("innertext")
comptext = "This is a header" 
strmatch = Instr(1, mytext, comtext)
if strmatch <> 0 then
print "the text matches"
end if
```

'if strmatch returns 0 then there is no match

Answer (score 0):

Great one! Try this too

```
If Browser("title:=HRnet"). Page("title:=HRnet").WebElement("innertext:=No news to display.").Exist Then
  Msgbox "Text found"
Else
  Msgbox "Text not found"
End If by
```

[fresh quotes](http://www.freshquotes.org)